# I deleted a file from the GitHub interface and have not yet pulled the change down to local branch, how do I revert?

Tags: git, github

Basically title.

I accidentally deleted a file from the GitHub website, and I have not pulled the commit down to my local repository yet. How can I undo this file deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to take the back-up of file which you have in your local machine and then take pull and add the file which you have in local and push it to repo. Not sure if it can be reverted from github directly.

Comment: Is there any way to maintain the commit history of this file?

Comment: Commit history is visible on Github. Go to project -> code , here you can see the history which gets maintained by default

Comment: also each file history is also maintained, which is also visible in github.